# what is the difference between user defined package and system defined java package with respect to accessing static content

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static, scjp

> Q) With respect to accessing static content, what is the difference
>   between user defined package and java system package (say java.lang
>   etc)

I'm preparing for ocjp6. using 1.6.26 java version

my java program has a package named "pack" in PackageTest.java

```
package pack;
public class PackageTest {
    public static final int i=20;
  }
}

javac -d . PackageTest.java
```

created PackageTest.class file in pack folder

now accessing static contents of PackageTest class from another java

program (TestStaticContents.java) as below

```
import pack.PackageTest.*; 
// here importing all contents of PackageTest class
class TestStaticContents {
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("normal import, accessing i value with class name: "+PackageTest.i);
    }
}

javac TestStaticContent.java
```

displaying Compilation Error:

```
TestStaticContents.java: cannot access PackageTest bad class file: .\PackageTest.java
```

If i try accessing static contents of Math class from my java program
 its not displaying any compilation error i.e

```
import java.lang.Math.*; 
// here importing all contents of Math class
class TestMathStaticContents {
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("normal import, accessing pi value with class name : "+ Math.PI);
    }
}

javac TestMathStaticContents.java
```

No Compilation Error, and PI value is printed as expected.

Why this behavior is different compared to User defined package?

Comment: @NathanHughes This is correct.  OP, you can call `import static pack.PackageTest.*;` to gain access to all non-private static fields and methods within `PackageTest.java`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. but

Comment: but NathanHughes, why this is behavior is different compared to system defined packages. and @JacobG. i know using static import we can gain access to all non-private static data members. want to know why this difference for user defined packages with system defined packages. -karusai

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but I don't see any difference.

Comment: Also disregard Nathan's comment, the import is perfectly valid; I believe he misunderstood the question, as did I.  However I provided an answer to clear any confusion.

Comment: @JacobG. question is simple, why the system package behavior is different compared to user defined package when accessing public static datamembers. Here if you observe, system package i.e java.lang which has Math class and PI as static datamember being accessing without any errors but when we try accessing user defined package i.e pack which has TestPackage class and i as static datamember not allowing to access, displaying compilation error). Thinking is this a bug in java.

Comment: @karusai It's not a bug, I posted the solution 6 minutes ago below!

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand your problem now.  You've placed both `PackageTest.java` and `TestStaticComponents.java` in the same package, `pack`.  Two classes that share the same package cannot explicitly import one another.

You've hinted at this yourself by providing `TestStaticComponents.java` with a package-private class identifier.

Your import statement works perfectly if both classes reside in different packages.

Comment: i feel what you are saying is completely different, could you please read my question again,

Comment: @karusai I've read your question.  Your code does not compile because `PackageTest.java` and `TestStaticComponents.java` are both located in the package, `pack`.  Therefore, attempting to explicitly import either class within the other will **not compile**.  Because both classes share the same package, explicitly importing either class is not required, as you already have implicit access to their methods.

Comment: @karusai If you want `TestStaticComponents.java` to compile, simply remove the import statement: `import pack.PackageTest.*;`

Comment: sorry @JacobG, thanks for your analysis but that's not correct. Please read again, TestStaticContents.java is a different file and it is importing (i.e import pack.PackageTest.*;). PackageTest.java is a different file which is creating required package for TestStaticContents.java.

Comment: @karusai What do you mean by "creating required packages for"?  A class cannot create a required package for another, at least not until JDK 9's module system is released in July.  I believe you're simply confused about the problem that you encountered, but my solution ameliorates it.

Comment: @karusai Also, it's obvious that both classes are different files, but they reside in the same package like I had said multiple times.

Comment: My question is simple. When we can access static members Math class which is in system package i.e java.lang  (after import java.lang.Math.* ), why we are not able access static members of TestStaticContents class which is in user defined package pack (after import pack.PackageTest.*; ), hope i'm bit more clear now.

Comment: "but they reside in the same package like I had said multiple times." this is not correct, they are different.

Comment: @karusai What package is `TestStaticContents.java` in then?  The default one?

Comment: @karusai What version of Java are you compiling with?  I recreated the problem myself and it compiles just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

`import java.lang.Math.*` attempts to import the *nested types* from `Math`, not the static members. You should be using `import static`:

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI; //recommended to avoid wildcards
```

When using imported static members, you do not need to reference the class when using the member: You can use `PI` instead of `Math.PI`.

> No Compilation Error, and PI value is printed as expected.

This is because `java.lang.Math`, like all types in the `java.lang` package, is automatically imported: there's no need to import it. Because of this, `Math.PI` isn't causing an error like you'd expect.

If you used `PI` instead of `Math.PI`, you would have gotten an error, informing you the static member wasn't imported.